# Join completed, can't set field from the table add for my graduated map

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I've two thing that I joined, a shapefile of PollingStation and a csv of the results of the election. When I join them by the right field, I get a new table with all the information I need.

[image]

My problem is when i go to the layer properties and I choose a graduated map I can't choose field from the dataset I add.

[image]

I've seen that my data are as `string` for the dataset I add, and as `double` for the original.

So i extracted again my data from R, but this time I first set it as `character`to be sure. But when I joined it's always `string`.

I tried to refactor with the `refactoring field` tool, so I set all as `double`,

[image]

the tool says that it worked

[image]

but when I open the properties my data are always as `string`.

[image]

So Basically what I need is a way to join my data and make the field from the dataset I add usable for a graduated map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick and lame solution is to use expression and do the type conversion using something like :

```
to_integer("my_field")
```

*(or to_real)*

Then your symbology is set not on the "direct" field value but on a calculated version of the field and should work ...

Another solution is to setup **a .csvt file** which will define the type of each field of your .csv (some help : [How to Specify Data Types of CSV Columns for Use in QGIS](https://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/)) ...

Comment: I used the csvt file and it worked !

Comment: Good to hear ... where do your data come from _(if i may ask ?)_ ...

Comment: the shp data come from Open data : https://opendata.paris.fr/explore/dataset/secteurs-des-bureaux-de-vote/information/ ,   the results about the election come from here https://github.com/aktiur/resultats-electoraux/tree/resultats/data but you can find original data here : https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/election-presidentielle-2017-resultats-par-bureaux-de-vote-tour-1/table/?flg=fr&disjunctive.libelle_de_la_commune

Comment: Thanks ... i didn't know polling results were available (as downloadable open **numeric** data) ....